# n for Hopkins statistics using get_clust_tendency

Tags: r, clustering, unsupervised-learning

I started to use the [Hopkins statistics](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/print.php?id=238#hopkins-statistic) to establish, if a dataset is 'clusterable'.

I am using the following code - taken from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/factoextra/versions/1.0.5/topics/get_clust_tendency):

```
data(iris)

# Clustering tendency
gradient_col = list(low = "steelblue", high = "white")
get_clust_tendency(iris[,-5], n = 50, gradient = gradient_col)
```

Here n is set to 50. Obviously, because everyone knows that the iris clusters are of size 50. How do we chose n in the real world though? Any input would be very much appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is not related to the class size.

It's a sample size you need to choose according to how precise you want the estimate to be. A larger sample will give you a better estimate.

IMHO, Hopkins is useless for testing clusterability. It is a test for *multivariate uniform distributions*. But that never is a problem that your data is uniform, is it?

To see the effect of n, try n from 1 to 1000 in the Iris data set. Do 10 iterations each, and plot mean and standard deviation each. You'll see that with small `n` the estimate is much less reliable. Such an analysis would be possible in unknown data, too: do Hopkins several times, and if the scores vary too much, increase `n`.

Comment: Thanks which other measure would you recommend please?

Comment: I don't think there are any, except trying to cluster with many different algorithms. Data is complex, and put theoretically tractable models are simple (eg. Uniform, Gaussian).